# Can I use a CD instead of a USB for boot-repair

Tags: grub2, windows, boot-repair

Am I capable of using a CD instead of a USB for using boot-repair to fix my grub boot loader after upgrading to windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Nothing is wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can! But I would recommend using USB instead of CD because booting from USB is faster than CD